# "pick" vs. "choice"

Tags: word-usage

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/choice)

> Harvard was not his first **choice**.

> She would be my first **choice** for the job.

Where "choice" means "a person or thing that has been chosen or that can be chosen".

"pick" with the meaning of "[a choice, or something that is chosen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pick)" seems like a synonym.

Is the following sentence natural? Does it mean the same thing as quotation?

> Harvard was not his first **pick**.

---

Someone might think it is not appropriate to use "pick" when talking about college. However, in one episode of‎ the TV show "[Friends](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/)", one character (Ross Geller) says

> And everyone's telling me, "You gotta **pick a major**, you gotta pick a major." So on a dare, I picked paleontology. And you have no idea what I'm saying because, let's face it, you're a fetus. You're just happy you don't have gills any more! [src](http://www.tv-quotes.com/shows/friends/quote_2868.html)

Comment: For some reason, American sports commentators often seem to prefer ***pick*** over [the idiomatic standard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+his+first+pick+for%2Cnot+his+first+choice+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20his%20first%20choice%20for%3B%2Cc0) ***choice*** here.

Comment: Perhaps Harvard was not his first pick because he realised his choice of non-idiomatic standards would never get past the interview.

Comment: Compare https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126487/pick-vs-select-vs-choose?rq=1 To speak of 'picking' a university doesn't seem at all right to me; I would pick a chocolate from a box, or a pizza from the menu, but not something as important as which university to attend!